# Adding unit tests to a F# project in VSCode

Tags: unit-testing, f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake, ionide

I'm using VSCode and the Ionide suite of packages to create a console application in F#.  I need to add unit tests to the application so that when I `ctrl+shift+p FAKE: Build` the project, the tests are run during the build process.

I've created a [dummy project in Github](https://github.com/stevenranney/TestProj) as an example.

Initially, the `test` dir was not there.  I created the `test` dir and into that folder created a second project `TestProj.Test` (in hindsight, I should have used more descriptive names) for testing purposes.  I added the `.fsproj` file from `TestProj` to this project so that I could reference the `SimpleFunctions.fs`.  `NUnit.Framework` and `FsUnit` are added to the `TestProj.Test`.  `Test.fs` contains two simple tests.

I intentionally created the `TestProj.Test` as an F# `library` because I read on SO that the testing project needed to be a library rather than a console app.

I added lines 9, 31-37, and 47 to the default [`build.fsx` file that comes from Ionide.](https://github.com/stevenranney/TestProj/blob/master/build.fsx).  However, when I build the whole project (i.e., `TestProj`), the build fails and I get the following error:

```
  1) System.Exception: NUnit: cannot run tests (the assembly list is empty).
   at Fake.NUnitSequential.NUnit(FSharpFunc`2 setParams, IEnumerable`1 assemblies) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\UnitTest\NUnit\Sequential.fs:line 22
   at FSI_0005.Build.clo@31-3.Invoke(Unit _arg3)
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 492
```

[Line 22 of the `Sequential.fs`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/UnitTest/NUnit/Sequential.fs) suggests that `assemblies` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?  How should I set up the `build.fsx` file so that the tests in `TestProj.test` run successfully?  Alternatively, is there something wrong with the `Tests.fs` file in `TestProj.Test`?  This seems particularly difficult; is there an easier way to include tests that run automatically with VSCode, Iondide, and `F#`?

Comment: Your 'Test' target is looking for 'NUnit.Test.*.dll' whereas 'TestProj.Test' produces a like-named dll. BTW, there are a few other possible improvements to your project structure. If you want, I'd raise a PR by EOD WEST.

Comment: For setting up a full-fledged F# project including documentation you could have a look at [ProjectScaffold](https://fsprojects.github.io/ProjectScaffold/)

Comment: I've used ProjectScaffold before but there's so much stuff included that I don't need or understand.  I was hoping to avoid that but may resort to having to use it if I can't get a testing framework up and running on my own.  Also, maybe it's too early in my day, but I don't understand the abbreviations "PR," "EOD," and "WEST" as you've used them here.  Explanation please?

Comment: Sorry, for that wall of abbreviations :-) PR = *P*ull *R*equest for your repository, EOD = End Of Day, WEST = West European Summer Time. Did the answer help though?

Comment: Your comment helped minimally but that's because I don't understand how all of the parts fit together!  Also yes, a PR would be helpful!

Comment: created [PR](https://github.com/stevenranney/TestProj/pull/1) as promised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your project:

- trying to test before build `"Clean" ==> "Test" ==> "Build" ==> "Deploy"`
  => change target dependencies to `"Clean" ==> "Build" ==> "Test" ==> "Deploy"`
- separate paket configuration for test (paket.dependencies, paket.lock in `test` subfolder) which leads to inconsistent versions of referenced dependencies
  => remove `paket.dependencies` and `paket.lock` from `test`
- poisonous mix of NUnit versions
  => remove explicit references to `NUnit.Framework` from `paket.dependencies` and run `paket.exe install`
- invalid type extension in test project
  => change to `type Test()` or delete useless file
- building creates output of *all* projects (and not just `src/app`) in `./build` but tests look for DLLs in `./test`
  => change test file pattern to `buildDir + "**/*.Test.dll"`
- if you want to use NUnit3
  => `open Fake.Testing` and use `NUnit3` instead of `NUnit`

finally, you should [commit paket.bootstrapper.exe](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/getting-started.html)

I recommend you either use a predefined template or start small and make sure you understand each step and check that it is working as expected. Once you've run over the point of a non-working solution it is extremely hard to get back on track.